# How to fetch info from curly braces using Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to fetch info using Athena, I don't know much about the Athena service of AWS. Could anyone help me how to fetch this particular info i.e. **"Attribute4": "RSQ"**. I am pasting a demo data in JSON format to give better understanding how the data is structured.

I will grateful if you could give explanation and any document that will help me to enrich my knowledge regarding Athena querying style.

`{ "ID": "1234", "Name": "XYZ", "Age": "29", "address": { "street": "ABC", "houseno": "PRQ", "attributeDetails": { "Attribute1": "FGH", "Attribute2": "KLM", "Attribute3": "LMN", "Attribute4": "RSQ" }`

Athena Query which I am trying to write

**select ID, address.attributeDetails FROM "TableName"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athena is using Presto sql engine which has several functions to work with [json](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html), in this case you can use `json_extract_scalar` to get the id and `json_extract` for `attributeDetails`:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(json_str) AS (
    VALUES ('{ "ID": "1234", "Name": "XYZ", "Age": "29", "address": { "street": "ABC", "houseno": "PRQ", "attributeDetails": { "Attribute1": "FGH", "Attribute2": "KLM", "Attribute3": "LMN", "Attribute4": "RSQ" }')
)

-- query
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json_str, '$.ID'), json_extract(json_str, '$.address.attributeDetails')
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | {"Attribute1":"FGH","Attribute2":"KLM","Attribute3":"LMN","Attribute4":"RSQ"} |